# how to create a git patch on merge of PR?

Tags: git, github

We have two repos:

1. Development
2. air gapped

We need to copy code from development repo to air gapped repo as and when a new PR is merged to the development repo.
How can we create git patch based on PR merge which could contain multiple commits?

Answer (score 0):

Don't patch, [bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). It's how you do sneakernet history transport in Git.